# Trying To Use Clifford Algebra Package in Python/Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I installed the "clifford" package, or at least so I believed.  Here is what I executed:

```
import clifford as cf
layout, blades = cf.Cl(4)
```

Here's the result:

```
  File "C:\Users\asdf\Documents\4D\Python\clifford.py", line 10, in <module>
    layout, blades = cf.Cl(3)

AttributeError: partially initialized module 'clifford' has no attribute 'Cl' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Now what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file is called `clifford.py` hence it creates another python module called `clifford` and trys importing from there.
Renaming your file should work